# Error at <img> tag in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have this code

```
<a href="~Home.aspx">
<img style="float:left;margin-left:1px;" src=~img/head/acasa.png 
        title="Acasa" />
</a>
```

and when I start the project , VS returns me this error "**Error 38 Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory."**

What`s is the problem ??

This code id part of a control *ascx

Comment: That should probably be "~/" (note the slash after tilde) in both cases....

Answer (score 5):

You need to adjust the `src` and quote it, and add `runat="server"` if you want to relatively resolve it to application root:

```
<img style="float:left;margin-left:1px;" 
     src="~/img/head/acasa.png" title="Acasa" runat="server" />
```

The same applies for the anchor:

```
<a href="~/Home.aspx" runat="server">
```

Comment: @Alynuzzu - Then your error isn't here, it's something that starts with a `src="../"` or `href="../"` most likely elsewhere, a stylesheet or javascript include maybe?